# Erro em python comando exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, exec

Estou tentando realizar uma ação através do comando `exec()`:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main(a): #função que executará o comando
    exec(a)

c="""browser = await launch() #inicializa navegador
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR', timeout= 0) #timeout = 0 serve para impossibilitar erro por timeout
    dimensions = await page.evaluate('''() => {
        return {
            "width": document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            "height": document.documentElement.clientHeight
        }
    }''') #define as dimensões do navegador
    await page.setViewport(dimensions)
    await page.click('.tlid-open-source-language-list', button='left')
    await page.screenshot({'path': r'C:\Users\Windows 7\Desktop\yes.png'})
    await browser.close() #fecha navegador
"""
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(c)) #executa a função main()
input('fim')
```

O interpretador indica um erro como `invalid syntax` na linha `browser = await launch()`, e esse código funciona perfeitamente quando executado diretamente, então há algo de errado quando ele é inserido em uma string e depois é exec().

Por sinal, o seguinte código funciona muito bem:

```
def x(y):
    exec(y)
x('''print("oi")
print('tchau')''')
```

Portanto o problema não é o fato de uma multi-line string ser exec(). Como tudo que o interpretador indica é `Syntax Error: invalid syntax`, não sei como fazer o código funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com esta [resposta no overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859165/async-exec-in-python/53255739#53255739), efetuar exec() de uma string multilinhas gera complicações na formatação do código, logo é necessário introduzir a função em outra função que previnirá o erro.

O código corrigido é:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main(a):
    exec(f'async def __ex(): ' +
        ''.join(f'\n {l}' for l in a.split('\n'))
    )
    return await locals()['__ex']()

c=r"""browser = await launch()
page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR', timeout= 0)
dimensions = await page.evaluate('''() => {
    return {
        "width": document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        "height": document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }
}''')
await page.setViewport(dimensions)
await page.click('.tlid-open-source-language-list', button='left')
await page.screenshot({'path': r'C:\Users\Windows 7\Desktop\yes.png'})
await browser.close()
"""
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(c))
input('fim')
```